# Moving mysql database from Mac to Windows

Tags: database, windows, osx-snow-leopard

I am creating a database for someone with a MacBook Pro and will be developing it on a windows 7 system. How should I move the database from my system to the Mac system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may belong on another stack.

You can develop the site on your equipment and recreate the model on the client machine once you get it to work. It would need minimal tweaking if any at all. Run your create script and move/copy over your php, or other script, files on the target machine.

WAMP merely describes the components of your environment. There are only a few exceptions where *AMP content wouldn't work across * host OS platforms.